# How can i plot my image in 3D?

Tags: image, matlab, matplotlib, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have an image on mat-lab and i would like to analyze the intensity of the light in the image.
I want to do some kind of 3-D plot so i can see it clearly and get from it the average of the intensity and other stuff.
Can someone tell me what command should i use and how? my knowledge on mat-lab is very poor.
I have tried to do a surf plot but it keeps telling me "Warning: CData must be double or single unless it is used only as a texture data "
and i don't know how to change the type or what can i do to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your image from `uint8` to `double` type. This way you'll be able to do more operations on Matlab in a more flexible way:

```
>> doubleImg = im2double( uint8Img );
```

Alternatively (if you do not have image processing toolbox):

```
>> doubleImg = double( uint8Img ) / 255.0 ;
```

Comment: My image is uint16, and i don't have image processing toolbox.

Comment: @Maayan then `doubleImg = double( uint16Img ) / ( -1 + 2^16 )` should do the trick for you. Shana Tova.

Comment: I turn it into double but the surf function isn't good in my case. Do you have any idea what function i can use so i will be able to see in a plot the different intensities in my image?

Comment: by the way thanks for the help and shana tova!

Comment: @Maayan it is unclear what exactly you are looking for. What's wrong with `imagesc` and `impixelinfo`? what exactly is your problem?

Comment: I didn't know these functions before.I think that they can help me, thank you.